# `Global tag is not allowed` exception in SnakeYAML 2.0

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I'm using SnakeYAML 2.0 to parse YAML files in Java. But I face a problem here. This is my `User` class:

```java
package ir.sharif;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {
    int id;
    String username;
    String password;
    List<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(int id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I use this code to serialize a `User` object:

```java
package ir.sharif;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(10);
        user.setUsername("Jack");
        user.setPassword("jackSparrow2023");
        List<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        friends.add(new User(1, "Trent", "FCB"));
        friends.add(new User(2, "Jordan", "LFC"));
        user.setFriends(friends);

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        yaml.dump(user, new FileWriter("src/main/resources/sample.yml"));
    }
}
```

And this is how my `sample.yml` file looks like after running `main` method:

```yaml
!!ir.sharif.User
friends:
- friends: []
  id: 1
  password: FCB
  username: Trent
- friends: []
  id: 2
  password: LFC
  username: Jordan
id: 10
password: jackSparrow2023
username: Jack
```

Now I want to deserialize this data and load it as a new `User` object:

```java
package ir.sharif;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/sample.yml")) {
            User user = yaml.load(reader);
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
}
```

But after running, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Global tag is not allowed: tag:yaml.org,2002:ir.sharif.User
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    !!ir.sharif.User
    ^
```

How can I solve it?

As I searched, I'm doing it right but I think the problem is caused because in version 2.0 there are some changes. I tried loading my object like this (I deleted `!!ir.sharif.User` line from YAML file):

```java
package ir.sharif;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/sample.yml")) {
            User user = yaml.loadAs(reader, User.class);
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine. But if I want to deserialize the object serialized by SnakeYAML itself, I can't use this method. What should I do? I appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to register a `TagInspector` that allows your tag:

```java
var loaderoptions = new LoaderOptions();
TagInspector taginspector = 
    tag -> tag.getClassName().equals(User.class.getName());
loaderoptions.setTagInspector(taginspector);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(User.class, loaderoptions));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that allows to load **any** class, so it makes SnakeYAML 2.0 **unsafe** again.

**Use at your own risk!**

```java
LoaderOptions loaderOptions = new LoaderOptions();
loaderOptions.setTagInspector(tag -> true);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(loaderOptions);
User user = yaml.loadAs(inputStream, User.class);
```

It uses `TagInspector` imlementation (`tag -> true` lambda) that accepts any class.

Genrally, you should perfer other solutions with more granular control. But sometimes you can't know beforehand which classes you will need to construct (e.g. in a library), but at the same time the `.yaml` source is 100% trusted. In this case this solution is acceptable. But still, consider it as a last resort.